# Proxy class not created after adding reference

Tags: c#, web-services, visual-studio-2012

First of all, i am quite new to C# and such technologies, so sorry if I name something wrong, or my question is really stupid. I tried to fix that problem for some hours.

I got a project in which I have to connect to webservice. I have some example code that should work for that webservice (unfortunately i didn't copied it so I can't post it here now). The webservice name is "Service1".

What I did was that I added Webservice reference in Visual Studio - i pasted URL of that webservice and it's name appeared in box, so I accepted. Even though some classes were created (f.e Service1Soap, Service1SoapClient), there was no class Service1, which is used in sample code I got to connect to that webservice.

The code was something like:

```
var service = new ReferenceName.Service1();
```

And the error was, that "The type or namespace name 'Service1' could not be found". It's not namespace problem, because I can use Service1Soap();.

Any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: I suspect that Service1Soap is what you're looking for, even though the name is different.

Comment: As far as I remember, there was another error when trying to use this class - something about the fact that object of this class couldn't be created (like it was abstract or something). Sorry, I don't have access to that code and compiler now. Anyway - thanks for reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is:
 1. Right click in solution explorer
 2. Choose "Add Service Reference"
 3. Click "Advanced"
 4. Click "Add Web Reference"
 5. Paste URL

I thought that if I add "Service Reference" then it is what I want. It wasn't.